# Mobile - body:before background image briefly breaks when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

When I scroll on my website there is a white bar at the bottom of my background image. The image is attached to `body:before {}`. I have tried a variation of CSS settings and tricks to circumvent this but I can't seem to get around it. I even tried having the image `overflow 110vh` to prevent the white-space but that also failed.

Example of the issue below. Perhaps this is strictly iOS related? I am using iOS 10 and I have tried both Chrome and Safari and the issue persists on both.

[image]

Here is my [website](https://brotherhoodgaming.net):

Here is my CSS:

```
body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 110vh;
  z-index: -10;
  background: url(../css/images/brotherhoodSmall.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Any suggestions for this one? I've already had to use this crazy `body:before` workaround because `background-attachment:fixed` doesn't work well on iOS mobile devices.

Thanks

Comment: Unable to reproduce..

Comment: I have added some context and an example. I wonder if this may be iOS related somehow, not sure if you are on an iOS device or not.